# Gulp file compiling SCSS doesn't appear to do anything

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, gulp

I am trying to compile my SCSS using a gulp.js file, from within PHPStorm. Does anyone see what I have done wrong? The output doesn't show any errors.

The output shows:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/UserName/Desktop/mywebsite/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js --color --gulpfile /Users/UserName/Desktop/mywebsite/gulpfile.js compile-web-scss
[13:49:25] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/mywebsite/gulpfile.js
[13:49:25] Starting 'compile-web-scss'...
[13:49:26] Finished 'compile-web-scss' after 613 ms

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But the update CSS file is never created.

Here is the gulp.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var path = require('path');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var open = require('gulp-open');

var WebPaths = {
  HERE: './',
  DIST: 'dist/',
  CSS: './public/web/css/',
  SCSS_TOOLKIT_SOURCES: './public/web/scss/now-ui-kit.scss',
  SCSS: './public/web/scss/**/**'
};

gulp.task('compile-web-scss', function() {
  return gulp.src(WebPaths.SCSS_TOOLKIT_SOURCES)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(WebPaths.HERE))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(WebPaths.CSS));
});
```

Here is the file paths.

[image]

Comment: I feel like some information is missing because I see a now-ui-kit.css in the correct location?

Comment: That's the default version that came with the kit. I have since modified the SCSS file and am attempting to recompile.